# Getting images from the XML Links

Tags: ios, xml, xpath

http://www.cinejosh.com/news/3/40889/high-court-dismisses-andhra-poris-case.html

In above link I have this tag

```
<img src="/newsimg/newsmainimg/1433410900_andhra-pori.jpg" alt="High Court Dismisses 'Andhra Pori's Case" class="img-responsive center-block visible-xs">
```

I have the above tag and I need to get the image on imageview.

My code is like this

```
  NSString *gossipsXpathQueryString = @"//td//img";
  //imageGossipsNodes is  the array to get data
  imageGossipsNodes = [gossipsParser searchWithXPathQuery:gossipsXpathQueryString];
  for (TFHppleElement *element in imageGossipsNodes) 
  {
    NSString *imageUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.cinejosh.com%@", [element objectForKey:@"src"]];
  }
```

Now I want to pass the string for getting images.How to achieve this?Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options Synchronous and Asynchronous options. Try to use async methods.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
yourImageView.image = image;
```

or

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{

    NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        yourImageView.image = image;
     });
});
```